# Saved object not being read from sd card

Tags: java, android, file-io, sd-card, andengine

So in an android game (using andEngine) I'm making, I'm trying to save a TMXtiled map as an object and recall it later to save loading time. I have managed to get the files on the sd card but am having trouble trying to read from the sd card. This is the code I used to write the file:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(root + "/fileTest");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(tmxLoader.loadFromAsset(mContext, "tmx/test.tmx"));
oos.close();
```

Then I use this to read the file from the sd card:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(root + "/fileTest"); 
ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(in); 
mTMXTiledMap = (TMXTiledMap) os.readObject();
os.close();
```

The error I keep getting is a null pointer exception, which is what led me to believe that the file is not being read. I tested this method in java before using it in android and it works, however I was using strings. Is there something wrong with the code above? Also is there a better method for storing these large objects? Another thing I noticed was that the file on the sd card was around 3KB, but I have seen the TiledMap take a lot more space by using the DDMS, so does that mean the files are not being completely written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya i think you hadnt given the full path ie with the extension as

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(root + "/test.tmx");
```

hope this will solve your issue

Comment: The above code is a tad bit confusing since I use test as both the TMX name and the name of the file on the sd card. On the the sd card there is no extension on the file. I'll edit the above code to make it more obvious.

Comment: you need to give extension in both while writing & reading too

Comment: you can't leave it as a plain file. I thought if you made an object from a class that implements serializable, then the file name shouldn't matter?

Comment: but i think you must specifY(standard way) to make it perfect, try it once!!! Man

Comment: can you point out where exactly error is coming or can put Logcat error

Comment: This is the interesting line from logcat:08-13 11:55:32.942: WARN/System.err(9079): java.io.WriteAbortedException: Read an exception; java.io.NotSerializableException: android.util.SparseArray
. I guess that means that I need to serialize everything the object extends and implements not just the object itself. Although why it would let me write without giving me an error still perplexes me. Anyway, Thanks for the help.